# How to pass through window asking for basic auth credentials that appears when click link redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication

I have a website where most of pages are normally used via HTTP but some other pages are available only via HTTPS. Site is protected by basic auth (credentials are the same for HTTP and HTTPS pages).

When I open any HTTP page in browser (either FF or Chrome) and click link that leads to HTTPS page, browser shows alert that asks for basic auth credentials.

I have same issue with Webdriver (either FF or Chrome):
When I visit `http://username:password@some_domain.com` and click link that leads to HTTPS page, browser alert window that asks for basic auth credentials appears. Selenium doesn't "remember" credentials that were entered for HTTP page.

How can I follow this sequence of actions with Webdriver? If it's not possible what can you advice?

Comment: I ended up using AutoAuth as shown [here](http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/27/automatic-firefox-authentication-when-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoauth/) in Firefox. But I don't know how to solve this issue with Chrome.

Comment: You can use [autoit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621212/autoit-code-for-handling-windows-authentication-pop-up-using-selenium-webdriver) and handle the authentication window while using any kind of browser.

Comment: Currently I use Browsermob proxy for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
 FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
 profile.SetPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
 profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", hostname);
 Driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

hostname is your URL (example.com) then try to

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(http://user:password@example.com);
```

Comment: you can try to create a profile that had already authenticated then switch to it (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks)

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean This seems to be a different suggestion, so you should really post it as your own separate answer.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted twice. I did this and it worked for me without issue.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've been able to come up with so far is create a new Thread that handles a timeout.  As WebDriver doesn't return control on FF and other certain browsers, I can call the thread handler that then uses Robot to enter in the credentials and press enter (could also use AutoIt here).  Then the control is returned back to WebDriver to continue with script.

```
//put this where it belongs, say calling a new url, or clicking a link 
//assuming necessary imports 

int pageLoadTimeout = 10;
String basicAuthUser = "user";
String basicAuthPass = "pass";
String url = "https://yourdomain.com";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

TimeoutThread timeoutThread = new TimeoutThread(pageLoadTimeout);
timeoutThread.start();

driver.get(url);

//if we return from driver.get() call and timeout actually occured, wait for hanlder to complete
if (timeoutThread.timeoutOccurred){
    while (!timeoutThread.completed) 
        Thread.sleep(200);
}
else {
    //else cancel the timeout thread
    timeoutThread.interrupt();
}


public class TimeoutThread extends Thread {

    int timeout;
    boolean timeoutOccurred;
    boolean completed;

    public TimeoutThread(int seconds) {
        this.timeout = seconds;
        this.completed = false;
        this.timeoutOccurred = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(timeout * 1000);
            this.timeoutOccurred = true;
            this.handleTimeout();
            this.completed = true;

        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception on TimeoutThread.run(): "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void handleTimeout(){

        System.out.println("Typing in user/pass for basic auth prompt");

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            //type is defined elsewhere - not illustrating for this example 
            type(basicAuthUser); 
            Thread.sleep(500);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(500);

            type(basicAuthPass);
            Thread.sleep(500);

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        }
        catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to type keys: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```